# Omniauth Stripe Connect – How Can I Add Scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, omniauth, stripe-payments

I'm using the Omniauth Stripe-Connect gem and I'd like to add a scope, but the documentation does not cover this.  Here's what I'm trying right now, but the `scope` and `stripe-landing` parameters are not being included:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :stripe_connect, ENV['STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['STRIPE_SECRET'], { :scope => 'read_write', :stripe_landing => 'register' }
end
```

The gem/strategy:  https://github.com/isaacsanders/omniauth-stripe-connect

Answer (score 1):

With the above gem, adding scope and stripe_landing to the `Builder` does not work.

Instead use just this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :stripe_connect, ENV['STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['STRIPE_SECRET']
end
```

And then add in the parameters in your Omniauth link:

```
<a href='http://exampleapp.com/auth/stripe_connect?scope=read_write&stripe_landing=register'>Connect With Stripe</a>
```